# unable to ssh to AWS codecommit repository, public key contents change

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codecommit

Below public key (modified) when I upload to IAM changes to a different format:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDZeqQA7Uc+dsdfasWqqqqqqqqqqqqqq6hvmFLZHfoVsebiGkW5t0g6wCaaaaaaaaaaaaaauD0rsW/IoWsYC95Ax5Kdo5N1yGkIs2m1l6DP0JCx1FuZN6DPp4HcccccVmfA3s88BTC84890qdfffffffffffffffff1/0HSqJyBTGrplZcFSesX7cVUGRdiOEF1iBW743 xxxxx@xxxx-VirtualBox
```

changes to following format (modified) when I view the popup by clicking show SSH key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjAdddddddddddw0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2XqkAO1HPjT4wKDFl4J8
OmNe3CWrsdfasdfasdfR36FbHm4hpF111111111111Z
PXWsR1kVRbR9g8cfqqqqqqqqqqqveQMeSnaOTdchpCLNptZegz9CQsdR
bmTegz6eB67Vu/ddddddddvewyjrL18paSWVnx1u
3RdBn7+v7b8XIz7yFQb8ddddddddG7lokf/Rgp78dq9rln
LWN8HNrKfiJ0oR7xWEVNsSChuHNf9B0qicgUxq6ZWXBUnrF+3FVBkXYjhBdYgVu+
NwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Is this the reason I always get following error:

```
ssh git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
```

My config file (modified) is:
cat .ssh/config

```
Host git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
User APsssssssDDDDDDDwwwAQ
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I cannot understand what is going wrong. I used the instructions in 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-without-cli.html#setting-up-without-cli-add-key

Answer (score 2):

If you set up your SSH successfully, then use your SSH key ID to clone the repo:

```
git clone ssh://<YOUR_SSH_KEY_ID>@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<MY_REPO_NAME>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The "agent refused operation" message is an odd one. It might be possible that your ssh agent doesn't know which private key to use.

You could try doing

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and then attempting authentication again. Also, adding "-v" might give you more information about what's going on.

```
ssh -v git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` solved my issue using Mac

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your problem. Can you answer these questions to help us find what the issue is?

1. Can you confirm within the IAM settings that the User ssh key-id matches up with your .ssh/config file?
2. Are you seeing this issue on Windows or Mac? Does this happen with other IAM users that have this SSH key?
3. Can you try following the steps on this page, particularly step 3? Links below depending on if your Windows or Mac/Unix.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html

Answer (score -1):

Because you are trying to verify the `ssh` config from the eu-west-1 zone, and your config file is eu-central-1.